# Check If Index Exists in Array D

Tags: arrays, d

I apologize in advance if anything isn't clear enough.

While attempting to check if an index value exists of an array in D, I encountered an unexpected RangeError.
I'm attempting to make an array check function, and I wouldn't know how to check for a value in an array in D.
In C, I would use `arr[index]`.

Execution Error:

```
core.exception.RangeError@test.d(6): Range violation
----------------
??:? _d_arrayboundsp [0x100f855d9]
??:? int checkArray(immutable(char)[][]) [0x100f6715e]
??:? _Dmain [0x100f7832e]
```

Code:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.stdc.stdlib;
import core.sys.posix.unistd;

int checkArray(string[] arr) {
    if (!arr[1]) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

void main() {
    string base = "test";
    string[] cut = base.split(" ");
    checkArray(cut);
}
```

I currently use a Mac, and used DMD to compile the source.

Should I try some other checker, other than `arr[index]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, never ever check if an index is within an array by dereferencing it.

```d
bool check(int[] arr, size_t index)
{
    return index < arr.length;
}

unittest {
    assert(!check([], 0));
    assert(!check([1], 1));
    assert(check([1, 2], 1));
    auto testArray = new int[1024];
    //testArray[testArray.length] = 1; // this throws, so check should return false
    assert(!check(testArray, testArray.length));
}
```

enjoy